# Automatic Thumbnails/Screenshots for Chapter in HTML Video

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, vtt

I found some examples, where people used a canvas and javascript to take multiple screenshots of a running video.
You can see these examples [here](http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/html5-video-article-demos/thumbnails-demo.html) or [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/).

The code sets a time interval, draws the current timeframe to a canvas and uses this to create a screenshot.

I am wondering if it would be possible to use a similar technique, to automatically create a kind of preview for chapters of the video.
But this would require to grab a bunch of screenshots before the video started. 
I failed to implement this, so I would like to know, if it is at all possible.

I know that one could use pretaken screenshots for the chapters, but I wanted to automate this process.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done in theory by jumping to specific times in the video (say every 10 seconds) using `video.currentTime`, waiting for the frame to be available (using `progress` events), drawing the frame to a canvas (`canvas.drawImage`) and storing it in some way (say an array of images having `image.src = canvas.toDataURL`).

However, this process will take time because at least the relevant parts of the video would need to be loaded in the browser so the frame could be grabbed. The video would not be playable during the process as it is being skipped to different frames.

This behavior is usually not acceptable, but it really depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Hint: Use two `<video>` elements: One for the user to watch and one they can't see for taking screen grabs from.

Comment: Other hint : if the server can handle it, you could even use more `<video>` elements,  and set your video's src with a [playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range). Don't forget to kill the video elements once you've drawn it. Also, for memory, better to store Blobs than the dataURI string version.

Comment: Thank you, that where two ideas I came up with too, but had problem implementing. I didn't knew about the progress event.
I will try both to see, which one runs smoothest.

Comment: I made a demo here to see if the idea could work: http://codepen.io/giladaya/pen/ygzWKN it uses `oncanplay` event  (not `progress`) and it works but it's veeery sloooow